# Jest encountered an unexpected token when using TextField from Material UI

Tags: typescript, jestjs, material-ui

I've been on this problem for a full day now and I can't seem to get my Jest test to work. I think it has to do with using Material UI's TextField 'date' that uses moment.js

I'm getting the following error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /Users/linhlekim/Documents/Planned/entr-clients/node_modules/react-day-picker/src/moment.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export { MomentLocalUtils as default } from './addons/MomentLocaleUtils';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-day-picker/src/addons/MomentLocaleUtils.js:3:1)
```

I've tried several solutions online such as 1) renaming my `.babelrc` to `babel.config.json` 2) adding a pattern to my `jest.config.ts`

```
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    '/node_modules/(?!react-day-picker)', 
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$',
  ],
```

But nothing seems to work and I still get the same error.

My current configs are the following:

`jest.config.ts`

```
import { pathsToModuleNameMapper } from 'ts-jest/utils'
import { compilerOptions } from './tsconfig.json'

module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  moduleDirectories: [
    'node_modules',
    'src',
  ],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    '!**/*.d.ts',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
    '!**/legacy/**',
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/.next/', '/legacy/', '/*.test-helpers.(ts|tsx)'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|t|j)sx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    '/node_modules/(?!react-day-picker)',
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper:
    pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '<rootDir>/src/' }),
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: 'tsconfig.test.json',
    },
  },
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "paths": {
      "@assets": [
        "assets/index"
      ],
      "@assets/*": [
        "assets/*"
      ],
      "@components/*": [
        "components/*"
      ],
      "@config/*": [
        "config/*"
      ],
      "@hooks/*": [
        "utils/hooks/*"
      ],
      "@inputs": [
        "components/legacy/components/inputs-v2/index"
      ],
      "@inputs/*": [
        "components/legacy/components/inputs-v2/*"
      ],
      "@legacy/*": [
        "components/legacy/*"
      ],
      "@shared/*": [
        "components/shared/*"
      ],
      "@store": [
        "store/index"
      ],
      "@store/*": [
        "store/*"
      ],
      "@styles/*": [
        "components/legacy/styles/*"
      ],
      "@utils/*": [
        "utils/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/custom.d.ts",
    "src/global.d.ts",
    "src/utilities.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

`package.json`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.1.21",
    "@storybook/addon-controls": "^6.1.21",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.1.21",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.1.21",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.1.21",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@types/algoliasearch": "^3.34.10",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.15",
    "@types/cypress": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.153",
    "@types/mixpanel-browser": "^2.35.3",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
    "@types/react-geosuggest": "^2.7.10",
    "@types/react-imgix": "^9.0.3",
    "@types/react-inlinesvg": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/react-instantsearch-core": "^6.3.1",
    "@types/react-instantsearch-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.9",
    "@types/react-toggle": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/segment-analytics": "0.0.33",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.9.0",
    "acorn": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.7",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "cypress": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^3.10.2",
    "eslint-watch": "^6.0.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "node": "^12.20.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "react-inlinesvg": "^0.8.3",
    "react-intl-translations-manager": "^5.0.3",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "standard": "^12.0.1",
    "storybook-addon-designs": "^5.4.5",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.3",
    "typescript": "^3.9.3",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "vercel": "^21.1.0"
  },
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What if you remove `'/node_modules/',` from the `transformIgnorePatterns` array? 
The next line would mean: "ignore everything in `node_modules`, but `react-day-picker`"

Comment: [Here's a working example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62216912/637367) with lit-html

Comment: thanks @Teneff! So simple, it worked!